# Can't run node file using Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am trying to execute a file using the terminal included in Visual Studio Code. However, I cannot seem to get it working and end up receiving the following error message:

```
Example, "node myfile.js" --> module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module c:\somepath
```

Is there anyone who knows what the problem might be?

Comment: if you enter this command in VS powershell terminal: "npm config get prefix" does it gives you a path linked with your VS? If not, maybe 1- nodejs is not in your path; 2- you have not installed nodejs module by modifying your VS installation or 3- maybe a problem with VS version of nodejs.

Comment: Do you mean that it works in a regular PowerShell window but not in the integrated terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I had your problem before

you should run cmd as administrator.

then type : powershell set-Executionpolicy Remotesigned

and

enter.

now you can run node in vscode .

Comment: Hi Ali. Could you be more clear on your answer? For instance, which `cmd` you mean to "run as administrator" (is it VSCode, Node, Powershell?). Also, you don't have to say "enter". And for the benefit of clarity, put commands/code snippets in [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Hi Ali. Could you be more clear on your answer? For instance, which `cmd` you mean to "run as administrator" (is it VSCode, Node, Powershell?). Also, you don't have to say "enter". And for the benefit of clarity, put commands/code snippets in [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Run Visual studio as Admin and also the Node package location should be accessible for your user